# Date comparision with access database in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am stuck with a query to compare the current date with date stored in access database table in the given format 7/25/2012

I am using this query:

```
Sql = "SELECT max(token_today)
FROM token
WHERE issue_date = #" & FormatDateTime(Now,    DateFormat.ShortDate) & "#"
```

and I am getting the error below:

> conversion from string ** to type 'Integer' is not valid.

Please tell me how to compare the date.
Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to compare today's date, there is no need for an external reference:

```
Sql = "SELECT max(token_today) FROM token WHERE issue_date = Date()"
```

This saves all sorts of problems with locale, as well.

Answer (score 1):

i think this should work:

```
"SELECT max(token_today) FROM token WHERE issue_date = #" & FormatDateTime(Now,"YYYY/MM/DD") & "#"
```